# python web request timeout error (requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool)

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, get, request

i have wrote a python code take subdomain from file and do a web request i am using get method i set a timeout to 5 seconds, the code work perfect when the request take less than 5 seconds but when the request take more than 5 seconds it shows me an error. the error says **requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(..,..)**, i know there is something to do with **Exception Handling** but i do not know what is it.
below the code snippet:

```
import requests
import time 

subdomain = []
with open("test.txt","r") as test:
    lines = test.readlines()
count = 0 
for i in lines:
    count = count +1
    subdomain.append(i)

for urls in subdomain:
    
    make_request = requests.get(urls,timeout=5)
    print(make_request.status_code)
```

Comment: I believe your `requests.get(urls)` is calling too many `urls` at once, perhaps it should've been `for urls in subdomain: for url in urls`?

Comment: i am writing the code to do multi request (threading) but right now i did not implement it yet because i have this issue

Answer (score 0):

You may add a `try/except` around the request call, handling the good exception

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as test:
    subdomain = test.read().splitlines()
    count = len(subdomain)

for urls in subdomain:
    try:
        make_request = requests.get(urls, timeout=5)
        print(make_request.status_code)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
        print("Request to", urls, "timed out")
```

Also I don't suggest `f.readlines()` as it keeps the newline char at the end of each, rather a full read then split each lines

Comment: yes this works fine, and i figured out that even if use except only without requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout it would work

Answer (score 0):

I have removed some unnecessary parts of your code, and added the Exception as you asked for. Here's a working solution:

```
import requests
import time 

subdomain = []
with open("test.txt","r") as test:
    subdomain = test.readlines()
count = len(subdomain)

for urls in subdomain:
    try:
        make_request = requests.get(urls,timeout=5)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
        print("timeout", urls)
        continue
    print(make_request.status_code)
```

You can even get rid of the 2nd `for loop` as your reader is already a loop:

```
import requests
import time 

subdomain = []
count = 0
with open("test.txt","r") as test:
    for count, urls in enumerate(test):
        try:
            make_request = requests.get(urls,timeout=5)
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
            print("timeout", urls)
            continue
        print(make_request.status_code)
```